# How to convert '+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999', Max value of OffsetDateTime stored as String to LocalDate

Tags: java

In Java, How to convert '+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999', Max value of OffsetDateTime stored as String to LocalDate. I would like to convert all possible values including Max of OffsetDateTime which is stored as String to LocalDate.

Comment: Have you tried it already?

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse("+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999").toLocalDate()` ?

Comment: I tried LocalDate.parse("+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999"), but LocalDateTime.parse worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by parsing it in `LocalDateTime` then recovering the date part.

```
String maxDate = "+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999";
LocalDate date = LocalDateTime.parse(maxDate).toLocalDate();
```

And if you want to get the value from the constant directly, make sure to use the correct format :

```
String maxDate = OffsetDateTime.MAX.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
```